# FirebaseUI for firebase recyclerView in android - Expected 1 arguments but found 4

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android development and I'm facing a problem using firebase UI. I wanted to retrieve data from my firebase database and show it on my recyclerView. but I am constantly getting an error while making FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

here is my code:

[image: firebaseUserSearch]

And I'm getting an error in:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Users, UsersViewHolder> 
(
    Users.class,
    R.layout.list_layout,
    UsersViewHolder.class,
    mUserDatabase

)
```

Image of the error:

[image: image of error]

Comment: This error shows your adapter constructor has only one argument and you are passing 4.

Comment: Yeah I ended up fixing the issue, it was the Firebase Recycler Adapter that was out of date. I had to use Firebase Recycler Options instead.